# Python: appending one list inside a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have initialized a list of empty lists, like so:

```
>>> myList = [[]]*5
>>> myList
[[], [], [], [], []]
```

and I'm wanting to append one of those lists with something:

```
>>> myList[2].append(3)
```

but it appends `3` to all of my lists:

```
>>> myList
[[3], [3], [3], [3], [3]]
```

How can I append to just one of these lists?

Comment: You have a list with 5 references to a  *single list object*.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, thanks!